# What does str() do in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.6

In the code below, I'm unable to figure out what **str(word.strip(), encoding = "utf-8")** does. I tried to Google it but to no avail. Request someone to help me out:

```
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(str(word.strip(), encoding = "utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this casts the result of `word.strip()` to a string type, and specifically sets the encoding of this string to 'UTF-8'. You can find more details on `str()` here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking the object `word` and removing any whitespaces at the beginning and the end of `word` with `word.strip()`. After removing the whitespaces from `word`, it's returning `word` as a `utf-8` encoded string.

In effect, that line of code is just removing white spaces at the beginning and at the end of `word`.

You can find more information [str()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) and [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)